# netsuite saved search difference between two columns

Tags: netsuite

I am writing a saved search that shows SKU then monthly qty and $ value. i want to add a 3rd column that shows the difference in value between 1month ago and 2 months ago.

below is the formula however the result adds the two columns together rather than subtracts  can anyone helps with what i am missing here.

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTik3.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Saved Reports for this. This will find the difference between two columns. You can specify different periods for both the columns.

You can Navigate to Reports -> New Report and you can customize the required report.